# B2B Commerce: Error getting or creating webcart

Tags: apex, unit-test, connect-api

I'm trying to run some apex tests in our Webstore (there's just one in the org), in a scenario that the test class creates dummy user/account/contact/buyer group/products/cart to finally test some cart stuff.

`ConnectApi.CartSummary cart = ConnectApi.CommerceCart.getOrCreateActiveCartSummary(webstoreId, accIdUser, 'active');`

So, when testing this connectApi getOrCreateActiveCartSummary above, I get this error below:
[image: 'account XYZ does not belong to webstore WWW']

> ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: Argument: account '001QL000003ZtuT' does not belong to webstore '0ZE8F00000001...

Even with the proper webstore id (the only one from the org) and effective account id (the same I'm using in other apex tests and it's working fine there).

The "dummy" account is being created like that (below). I don't know if we're missing any info:

```apex
public static Id createAccount() {
    Account account = new Account();
    account.Name = 'Lorem Ipsum';
    account.Type = 'Customer';
    account.Phone = '1-434-555-2222';
    account.Website = 'https://dummy.org';
    account.B2B_SAPCustomerID__c = '123456789';
    insert account;
    System.debug('inside createAccount()');
    return account.Id;
  }
```

Am I missing something? I didn't find any doc regarding exacly this error.

Tks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assign the buyer group to the WebStore by creating a WebstoreBuyerGroup record.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_webstorebuyergroup.htm